# What's a good way to share a value in multiple places in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Let's say I have a value: `\\myServer\dir1\dir2\dir3`. I'd like this value to appear in multiple places in an MSWord document. However I only want to write it down once. What's a good way to do this? Fields seem like the answer but I can't get it to work; maybe it's not the answer.

I'd like to be able to do this without any macros; it adds too much complexity. I need something more like Excel -- write a cell value here, reference it there, change the original value and the reference gets updated too.

Edit: ideally I'd have the value updated automatically (fields don't seem to want to do that!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word 2007 you can use a [Quick Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/ha102140711033.aspx) to create reusable content. From the help docs:

> **Create a reusable content building block**
>
> 1. Select the text or graphic that you want to store as a reusable
>      building block.
> 2. On the Insert tab, in the Text group, click Quick Parts, and then
>      click Save Selection to Quick Part
>      Gallery. Or press ALT+F3.
> 3. Fill out the information in the Create New Building Block dialog box:
>
>    - Name:  Type a unique name for the building block.
>    - Gallery:  Select the gallery that you want the building block to
>        show up in.
>    - Category:  Select a category, such as General or Built-In, or create
>        a new category.
>    - Description:  Type a description of the building block.
>    - Save in:  Select the name of the template from the drop-down list.
>    - Options:  Select Insert content in its own page to ensure the building
>        block is placed on a separate page.
>        Select Insert in own paragraph for
>        content that should not become part of
>        another paragraph, even if the user's
>        cursor is in the middle of a
>        paragraph. Select Insert content only
>        for all other content.

You can find more detailed help as well in Word 2007 by clicking the Insert Tab > Expanding Quick Parts > F1 for help on Quick Parts.

**Edit 1**
Apparently Quick Parts are not dynamic which means child parts will not be updated when the parent is updated. Some possible alternatives:

1. [MSDN: Exploring the Dynamic World of Word 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637847.aspx)
2. [Word Custom Properties: How to Improve Productivity](http://www.chlankboot.com/blog/archives/1014/word-custom-properties-how-to-improve-productivity)

**Edit 2** (requested by OP to be added to answer)

> I think that for my use the Comments
>   document property works best. I need
>   one value in many places and I need it
>   to update automatically. The advanced
>   doc properties don't update
>   automaticaly (despite all efforts to
>   the contrary). But the basic document
>   properties do.

Comment: It looks like that will save the content into Building Blocks.dotx. Doesn't that mean that anyone who opens the document would also have to have Building Blocks.dotx? Also, I did what you said, then inserted the QuickPart in a different place, then edited the original and the copy didn't change.

Comment: It appears that Quick Parts are not bound which means child parts will not be updated :(  Check my edit for a possible alternative.

Comment: I think that for my use the Comments document property works best. I need one value in many places and I need it to update automatically. The advanced doc properties don't update automaticaly (despite all efforts to the contrary). But the basic document properties do. I can't edit your answer so please add that.

Comment: @jcollum - added update as requested :)

Comment: To update Custom Properties, select all (Ctrl-A) then press F9.